# Disable if there are no children - Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have some code that displays the children categories on the screen but some parent categories do not have children if that is the case I don't want the section to be shown. does anybody know a way to do this? here is my current code to show the categories:

```
<div class="list-group products box">
                        <h4>Product Range</h4>
                        <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                        $category_name = $term->name;
                        $parent_category_id = $term->term_id;

                        $categories=get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category_id ));
                    $children = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                                'parent'    => $parent_category_id,
                                'hide_empty' => true
                    ) );
                  foreach( $children as $subcat ){
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $subcat->slug, 'product_cat' ); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
                        <?php } } ?>
                </div>
```

When a parent as no children it just shows the H4 Product Range

Comment: means you do not want to show ` <h4>Product Range</h4>` if parent has no children?

Comment: bascially i want this section to be disabled so i cant see the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
<?php
  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $category_name = $term->name;
    $parent_category_id = $term->term_id;

    $categories = get_categories(array('parent' => $category_id));
    $children = get_terms('product_cat', array(
        'parent' => $parent_category_id,
        'hide_empty' => true
    ));
    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo ' <div class="list-group products box">
                                  <h4>Product Range</h4>';
        foreach ($children as $subcat) {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($subcat->slug, 'product_cat'); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
            <?php
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Replaced with current code and works wonders thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you.